# Receiving: [Error: invalid address (argument="address"....] with xdc

Tags: ethers.js

I am trying to create a transaction on the XinFin blockchain in the following way:

```
const tx = {
  from: walletManager.toEVMAddress(transaction.walletSafe.address),
  to: walletManager.toEVMAddress(transaction.to),
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther(transaction.amount.toString()).toHexString(),
  nonce: txCount,
};

try {
  await ethersWallet.sendTransaction(tx);
  //...
```

The tx data is as follows:

```
{"from": "0x...", "nonce": 0, "to": "0x...", "value": "0x0de0b6b3a7640000"}
```

I double checked and the from and to addresses are correct and not in XDC format as the above data shows.

But I am receiving the following error:

```
[Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="xdc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0)]
```

But nowhere I am using xdc as a prefix. I am using ethers v5.7.2.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?